# Chapter 9 test failed Ruby on rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im newbie in Rails and I am reading the Michael Hartl's RubyOnRails tutorial... I have read about Chapter 9 similar problems  but I didnt resolve my own problem, so here is my github repository and the failed test... Perhaps someone can help me, thanks so much ;)

https://github.com/AntonioCortinaL/sample_app

```
1) UserPages edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1',       text: "Update your profile") }
   expected css "h1" with text "Update your profile" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UserPages edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title',    text: "Edit user") }
   expected css "title" with text "Edit user" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:62:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) UserPages edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
   expected link "change" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) UserPages edit with invalid information 
 Failure/Error: before { click_button "Save changes" }
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no button with value or id or text 'Save changes' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:76:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Edit after Paul Fioravanti answer:**

Ok, thanks... I changed it for this:

```
 before do
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user) 
 end
```

Now its 5 errors

```
1) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Confirm Password' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Confirm Password' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Confirm Password' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Confirm Password' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Confirm Password' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Your **user_pages_spec.rb** test](https://github.com/AntonioCortinaL/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb#L57) says:

```
describe "edit" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
  # ...
end
```

You forgot to `sign_in` before `visit`ing the `edit_user_path`.

[Here's the tutorial's equivalent spec](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb#L200).

**Edit**:

As for your second issue see the equivalent link in the Rails Tutorial [here](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb#L179).  Compare your **user_pages_spec.rb** [here](https://github.com/AntonioCortinaL/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb#L24) and [here](https://github.com/AntonioCortinaL/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb#L81): you can see you're trying to `fill_in` a `"Confirm Password"` field and a `"Confirmation"` field, only one of which actually exists in your app...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've corrected but still 5 errors. I have compared the code that you have given me and I think is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you give each user a valid remember token using the rails console before running the test suite. Follow 8.2.4 for precise instructions.